# October CMS export data to CSV from backend

Tags: csv, export, backend, octobercms

Working on export data from October CMS backend 
searched trough the web for solution, nothing there, only pieces of the info.

I have JSON data taken from october CMS DB and I need to export it from backend to CSV file.

Tried also one of modules but without luck

It should be vary simple, there a whole page for it on October docs, but it looks incomplete.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial for using the import and export functionality. Take a look [here](http://octo-help.com/how-to-use-the-new-import-and-export-feature-in-october/)

And for working code example, check [this plugin](https://github.com/vojtasvoboda/oc-userimportexport-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

October cms has document explaining how to develop functionalities to download a csv from backend 
you can find the best help by looking it here [octobercms import,export](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/import-export)